# How do I Send base 64 string with Volley

Tags: android, asp.net, base64, android-volley

I am trying to send an image as a base 64 string with volley to .net core API this is my android code

```
public void SendImages(String file) {
        byte[] encoded =null;
        try {
            byte[] strBytes = Base64.decode(file, Base64.DEFAULT);
             encoded = Base64.encode(
                    strBytes, Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String   files = URLEncoder.encode("file", "utf-8");
        }catch (IOException i){

        }
        String URL = "http://192.168.8.104:45456/api/Image/UploadFileTwo/" + encoded;
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

and this is my API

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("{UploadFileTwo}/{base64}")]

        public void LoadBase64(string base64)
        {
            var decodedStr = Base64UrlEncoder.Decode(base64);

            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
            Image image;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            image.Save(base64);
         
        }
```

The problem is I am getting  "System.FormatException: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.' " on the API when i try to decode the base64 string

Comment: You decode in one line and encode in the next one. I cannot follow you.

Comment: And what was it that you decoded?